# select a column value as input parameter for a procedure

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I have a procedure written in Oracle, It takes one input parameter of type Number.
In my task I want to Select one column value from another table and give that value as input parameter to my procedure.

something like below,

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE GETXML_JOB_SP
(
 Select ID from Department AS inputVariable_ID IN;
)

AS
 O_JDATA  CLOB ;
 o_JDXmlData xmltype;
 o_JEXmlData xmltype;
 O_JEDATA CLOB;
 queryCtx dbms_xmlquery.ctxType;


BEGIN
O_JDATA := DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML('SELECT * from Emp where JOB_DTLS_ID='||inputVariable_ID );

o_JDXmlData := xmltype(O_JDATA);

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(o_JDXmlData.getClobVal) ; 
END GETXML_JOB_SP;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter definitions are incorrect. You can't put a select statement in as a parameter.

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE GETXML_JOB_SP
(
inputVariable_ID IN NUMBER
)

AS
 O_JDATA  CLOB ;
 o_JDXmlData xmltype;
 o_JEXmlData xmltype;
 O_JEDATA CLOB;
 queryCtx dbms_xmlquery.ctxType;


BEGIN
O_JDATA := DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML('SELECT * from Emp where JOB_DTLS_ID='||inputVariable_ID );

o_JDXmlData := xmltype(O_JDATA);

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(o_JDXmlData.getClobVal) ; 
END GETXML_JOB_SP;
```

I would recommend reading the [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/nav/portal_5.htm) on PL/SQL or the many online tutorials.

Comment: That's ok. but can we do as I shown in question, I mean I dont want to pass a parameter by myself it should be taken from select query itself..

Comment: Not sure sure I understand. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Hi in your case you need to create two procedure one is what "OldProgrammer" written

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE GETXML_JOB_SP
(
inputVariable_ID IN NUMBER
)

AS
 O_JDATA  CLOB ;
 o_JDXmlData xmltype;
 o_JEXmlData xmltype;
 O_JEDATA CLOB;
 queryCtx dbms_xmlquery.ctxType;


BEGIN
O_JDATA := DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML('SELECT * from Emp where JOB_DTLS_ID='||inputVariable_ID );

o_JDXmlData := xmltype(O_JDATA);

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(o_JDXmlData.getClobVal) ; 
END GETXML_JOB_SP;
```

and other procedure to call this proc with id as input parameter is

```
create or replace procedure GETXML_JOB_SP_call
is 
begin
   for x in (Select ID from Department)
     loop
          GETXML_JOB_SP(x.id);
     end loop;
end GETXML_JOB_SP_call;
```

you need call above procedure first.